# What event is triggered by SetFocus on MediaElement?

Tags: win-universal-app, mvvm-light

I need to change the `Source` of a `MediaElement` and start to play the new source.

Here is the data binding on the `MediaElement`.

```
<MediaElement x:Name="media" AutoPlay="False" Source="{Binding SpeakSource}"
                MediaEnded="media_MediaEnded" />
```

What event will be raised when `SpeakSource` on the view model is changed? Is it `Loaded`, or `DataContextChanged`, or something else?

Answer (score 0):

It must be `CurrentStateChanged` event which is raised when you change `MediaElement`'s `Source` property. Its state will change to `Opening`, then to `Buffering`, and then to `Playing`.